# Sql query formatação em apenas uma linha

Tags: query, formatação, notepad++, ssms, indentação

Em alguns casos, quando salvamos uma query .sql, mesmo estando indentada corretamente no SSMS ao abrirmos no notepad (windows) todo o texto fica numa linha só, juntando END com GO (ENDGO) ao final de uma alteração na procudere (por exemplo).

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Poderia falar um pouco mais de qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Se for no menu formatar > quebra de linha automática. Fica como vc quer? só não entendi a dúvida também.

Comment: Desculpa, publiquei esta pergunta, por que ocorreu este problema aqui na empresa. Já respondi apenas para deixar registrado rsrs... vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em alguns casos, pode ser o sistema operacional.
No Windows o enter gera um caractere especial "CR LF" mas no MAC o enter gera apenas "CR". No Windows, "CR" não funciona como quebra de linha.

No [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.5.4.html) é possível verificar essas quebras de linha buscando pela expressão regular "\r[^\n]", usando esta expressão regular, você encontrará caracteres especiais "CR".